# Ruby on Rails - Devise - Add redirects for custom account pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I have broken up the users 'edit' page into several different pages to make the UI better. 
I have 1 page for avatars and personal info, another for email and password change etc etc...

My issue is setting a redirect after updating info on each page. Eg. If I update the email address (located on the 'accounts' page), the user gets redirected to `users/edit` and not `users/account`.

I have set up the pages as follows:

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }
  devise_scope :user do
  get "/users/account", to: "users/registrations#account"
  get "/users/media", to: "users/registrations#media"
  get "/users/notifications", to: "users/registrations#notifications"
  end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
def account
     @user = current_user
     if @user
       render :account
     else
       redirect_to root_url
     end
   end

   def media
     @user = current_user
     if @user
       render :media
     end
   end

   def notifications
     @user = current_user
     if @user
       render :notifications
     end
   end
```

eg. devise/registrations/account.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
```

---

All the users attributes update correctly, the only thing I can't figure out is how to stop the page redirecting always to `users/edit`. As the page redirects, I lose my simple_form errors too.

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

When a user successfully updates his profile, he is now redirected to the correct page.

View.html.erb

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'page_id', "account" %>
```

devise registrations conroller.rb

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
      if params[:page_id] == "account"
        users_account_path(resource)
      else
        edit_user_registration_path(resource)
      end
end
```

---

My problem now is that if the update fails validation etc. the redirect is still to users/edit. I cannot find a way to change this.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: checkout: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile

Comment: I have read this previously and can get an 'overall' redirect, but I cant get each individual created page to redirect to itself (accounts page redirects to accounts page, notifications to notifications etc..). They all redirect to ´users/edit´ (which can be changed by following the link you posted. Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: for a simple solution of your problem , pass a extra parameter with resource or you can use hidden field, and check inside after_update_path_for, if ex_param == 'some_action' redirect to that page

Comment: Interesting idea, I will try that!

Comment: HMMM I have it working for when the account succesfully updates, but if it fails due to incorrect input, it reverts to users/edit again.

Comment: the other thing you can do is write your own devise update method with if else to check if user is updated or not

Comment: I am unable to get this working